# Not able to create an exact function template with generic vector as an argument

Tags: templates, c++11

I have a function to serialize parameters of any type. It works with all the types except when I pass a vector of any type.
I have created the following template:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool serialize(const std::vector<T>& v){}
```

But it does not work and it throws the below runtime symbolic error which looks for the below template specialization:

```
bool serialize<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >(rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)
```

Which, simplifying the templates, is really:

```
bool serialize<std::vector<std::string> >(rapidjson::Writer<>&, std::vector<std::string> const&)
```

Can someone help me to create an exact function template required for the above error?

Comment: What is the error exactly?  Paste the full text.

Comment: And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Hello John, the error is ./server: symbol lookup error: libserver-test.so: undefined symbol: _Z9serializeISt6vectorISsSaISsEEEbRN9rapidjson6WriterINS3_19GenericStringBufferINS3_4UTF8IcEENS3_12CrtAllocatorEEES7_S7_S8_EERKT_, after demangling it will come down to above specified explicit template.

Comment: `serialize` that you show implementation for takes one parameter. `serialize` that the linker complains about takes two parameters. Somewhere, you have a declaration with two parameters, lacking implementation.

Comment: @Igor: you are right. After demangling, I came to know how the explicit template specialization function for the required function template should look like. But not able to reverse engineer and create the generic function template, which can take generic vector as the template parameter. Say function template which can take vector<int> or vector<string>

Comment: The function that the linker wants takes the whole `vector<Something>` as a template parameter, not just `Something` as your version of `serialize` does. As far as I can tell, it wants an instantiation of `template <typename T> bool serialize(rapidjson::Writer<...>&, const T&)`. You can fully specialize this for `T == `vector<string>`, but there ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of function templates (you can, however, have the function delegate to a helper class template which can in fact be partially specialized).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I found a  simple solution. Mentioned the same as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
template <template <typename Value, typename Allocator  = std::allocator<Value>> class Container> class VectorWrapper;
template<typename T = decltype(VectorWrapper)>
inline bool serialize(writer_t& w, const T& v)
{ //code here }
```